# sympy collect returns dict, cant acess with key

Tags: python, dictionary, sympy

I'm using the Collect function to isolate some terms.
It returns a Dict and I can't access it using the key given. Here's the example:

```
import sympy as sp
t = sp.Symbol('t')
K1,K2,K3,K4 = sp.symbols("K1 K2 K3 K4")
W,R,L,C = sp.symbols("omega R L C")
Vi_t = 10*sp.cos(W*t)
Vi_yp_t = (1/L)*sp.diff(Vi_t,t)
Yp = K3*sp.cos(W*t)+K4*sp.sin(W*t)
dYp = sp.diff(Yp,t)
d2Yp = sp.diff(dYp,t)
malha = d2Yp +(R/L)*dYp + (1/L*C)*Yp
malha_separada = sp.collect(malha,(sp.sin(W*t),sp.cos(W*t)),evaluate=False)
```

Printing this gives:
[image: Copy/Paste here won't work well]

I can access key "1" with malha_separada[1], but any attempt I made with sin(omega*t) gives a key error.
Symbol, W, /omega...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `sp.cos(W*t)` and `sp.sin(W*t)`

```
import sympy as sp
t = sp.Symbol('t')
K1,K2,K3,K4 = sp.symbols("K1 K2 K3 K4")
W,R,L,C = sp.symbols("omega R L C")
Vi_t = 10*sp.cos(W*t)
Vi_yp_t = (1/L)*sp.diff(Vi_t,t)
Yp = K3*sp.cos(W*t)+K4*sp.sin(W*t)
dYp = sp.diff(Yp,t)
d2Yp = sp.diff(dYp,t)
malha = d2Yp +(R/L)*dYp + (1/L*C)*Yp
malha_separada = sp.collect(malha, (sp.sin(W*t), sp.cos(W*t)), evaluate=False)
print(malha_separada[1])
print(malha_separada[sp.cos(W*t)])
print(malha_separada[sp.sin(W*t)])
```

output:

```
C*(K3*cos(omega*t) + K4*sin(omega*t))/L + R*(-K3*omega*sin(omega*t) + K4*omega*cos(omega*t))/L
-K3*omega**2
-K4*omega**2
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. Swear that I did that before asking, must had made a typo.